# Drupal 7: событие по дате

Tags: drupal

Словарь таксономии: "статус мероприятия"
у него два термина "активное мероприятие" и "архив"

*статус мероприятия*

- активное мероприятие
- архив

Статус мероприятия выведен полем в тип материала, при создании мероприятия по умолчанию активен термин "активное мероприятие", по истечении даты редактируем материал и в ручную переключаем на архив. Так же в тип материала выведено поле дата.

**Вопрос:** *Есть ли возможность создать событие, которое меняет статус с активного на архив по истечении даты? Подскажите способ.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Drupal 7 есть такой функционал который назыветься Cron. Не нужно путать его с понятием cron в операционной системе. Если очень грубо говорить то это функция которая запускаеться при каждой загрузке сайта. Сначала она проверяет прошел ли установленный период с предидущего запуска, потом берет все хуки hook_cron и исполняет их. 
Здесь можно увидеть подтверждение этих слов и самостоятельно найти ответы на принцип  его работы.

**includes/common.inc**

```
function drupal_page_footer() {
  global $user;

  module_invoke_all('exit');

  // Commit the user session, if needed.
  drupal_session_commit();

  if (variable_get('cache', 0) && ($cache = drupal_page_set_cache())) {
    drupal_serve_page_from_cache($cache);
  }
  else {
    ob_flush();
  }

  _registry_check_code(REGISTRY_WRITE_LOOKUP_CACHE);
  drupal_cache_system_paths();
  module_implements_write_cache();
  drupal_file_scan_write_cache();
  system_run_automated_cron();
}
```

А ответом на вопрос будет

```
function MODULE_NAME_cron() {
  // Загружаете свои материалы которые имеют это поле в значении 
  // активное и дата уже прошла. 
  // Сначала нужно получить nid всех материалов которые подпадают под условие 
  // Потом загрузить эти матеиалы, изменить поле, и сохранить обратно
  // Можно использовать node_load, node_save,  а можно entity_metadata_wrapper 
  // и его методы
}
```

Comment: Через rules решение возможно?

Comment: да, там так же можно создать событие которое будет исполняться после запуска крон, например "Cron maintenance tasks are performed"

Comment: Ответ устраивает. Благодарю! Буду пробовать.